# ActiveAdmin Custom Scope with hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, hstore

I am attempting to write a custom scope for ActiveAdmin, but keep running into errors:

1. Search isn't performing
2. I keep getting an error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

**admin/user.rb**

```
filter :user_upload, label: 'User Upload Ability', as: :select, collection: [['On', 'false'], ['Off', 'true']]
```

**user.rb**

```
scope :user_upload, ->(value) { where('properties @> hstore(?, ?)', 'upload', value) }

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  :user_upload
end
```

**Example User**

```
#<User id: 1, name: "Example", created_at: "2015-03-14 07:00:00", updated_at: "2016-04-13 20:27:50", properties: {"upload"=>"false"}>
```

Not sure if I am going about the the correct way. Any ideas on how I can perform my scope so I can filter `users` by their upload property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to find out a solution for my question. Found this from:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/267#

Heres what I did for the fix:

**admin/user.rb**

```
filter :upload_eq, label: 'User Upload Ability', as: :select, collection: { 'On' => 'false', 'Off' => 'true' }
```

**user.rb**

```
ransacker :upload do |parent|
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:properties], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('upload'))
end
```

Turns out I didn't need to use the `ransackable_scopes` method in order to achieve this. And because I am using Rails 4.2 I had to wrap `build_quoted` around the `upload` property because I was getting a `unsupported: String` error (https://github.com/rails/arel/issues/323).